# Track any post with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have posted a thread on a website forum. Is there anyway to track views of that post with google analytics?

I remember that there was a method in which a white small image was added and behind that image, google tracking code resides. But I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ga.webdigi.co.uk/

Use this page to generate code and post it anywhere

Answer (score 1):

So, there's no *real* way to do this reliably with Google Analytics. The closest you can do is the following:

Create a unique Google Analytics account.
Paste the Google Analytics code on a page somewhere.
Using Firebug, Webkit inspector, Fiddler, or some other HTTP inspector, find out the value of the `__utm.gif` image request that your Google Analytics snippet generated.
Embed that image on your forum post.

Now, *none* of the resulting data will be reliable except 'Pageviews', and perhaps location. All of the data about computer configuration, source, etc. will just be shown as it is on the computer on which you initially created the original `__utm.gif`. That's because all of those values are set via JavaScript and dynamically used to create that image.

Comment: Thanks, but i found it almost. Just waiting to see if it works as expected